# Proof that range of projection matrix equals eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue of 1

Tags: linear-algebra

**Theorem**

Let $A$ be an idempotent, diagonalizable, $n \times n$ matrix. Then the range of $A$, $R(A)$, equals $E(A)_{\lambda = 1}$, the eigenspace of A corresponding to the eigenvalue 1.

**Attempted proof**

Let $v \in R(A)$. Then $Ax = v$ for some vector $x$. Now, 
$E(A)_{\lambda = 1}$ = $\{z \mid Az = z\}$, so if we can show that $x = v$, then $Av = v$, so $v \in E(A)_{\lambda = 1}$.

$$
Ax = v \\
AAx = Av \\
Ax = Av \\
Ax - Av = 0 \\
A(x - v) = 0
$$

Since A is diagonalizable, $A \neq 0$, so $x - v = 0$ and hence $x = v$. So $v \in E(A)_{\lambda = 1}$ and hence $R(A) \subseteq E(A)_{\lambda = 1}$

Conversely, let $z \in E(A)_{\lambda = 1}$. Then $Az = z$, so $z \in R(A)$ and hence $E(A)_{\lambda = 1} \subseteq R(A)$.

Thus, $R(A) = E(A)_{\lambda = 1}$.

$\blacksquare$

**Source**

Anthony, Harvey, *Linear Algebra*, 2012, Exercise 12.4.

There's a full proof in the back of the book, but it seemed very unintuitive to me, so I'm wondering if my proof above is also correct.

Comment: The zero matrix is diagonalisable, so you can't conclude that $A \neq 0$. Notice that $0$ is in fact an idempotent matrix, it just has a $1$-eigenspace of dimension 0.

Comment: Ah, of course! Is there an easy way to salvage the proof as it stands? Otherwise I'll accept your answer if you submit it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E:V\to V$ such that $E^2=E$.

If $Ey=y$ then clearly $y\in E(V)$.

If $y\in E(V)$ then $y=Ex$ for some $x$, and so $Ey=EEx=Ex=y$ and $y$ is in the $1$-eigenspace.

(Daigonalisability is free and irrelevant).

Comment: Ah, yes, from $Ax = Av$ I could've just concluded that $v = Av$ and hence $v$ in the 1-eigenspace.